# any faster alternative?

Tags: python, performance

```
cost=0
for i in range(12):
    cost=cost+math.pow(float(float(q[i])-float(w[i])),2)
cost=(math.sqrt(cost))
```

Any faster alternative to this? i am need to improve my entire code so trying to improve each statements performance.

thanking u

Comment: Rather than try to improve *each* statement individually, you should consider running a profiler to find out which statement(s) are taking the most time. Then, improve that section of your code. Otherwise, you're just going to be spending a lot of time on unjustified optimisation.

Comment: Folks are dumb where I come from: I thought Python profilers worked at the function/method level, not the statement level.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the general optimization remarks that are already made (and to which I subscribe), there *is* a more "optimized" way of doing what you want: you manipulate arrays of values and combine them mathematically.  This is a job for the very useful and widely used [NumPy package](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html)!

Here is how you would do it:

```
q_array = numpy.array(q, dtype=float)
w_array = numpy.array(w, dtype=float)
cost = math.sqrt(((q_array-w_array)**2).sum())
```

(If your arrays `q` and `w` already contain floats, you can remove the `dtype=float`.)

This is almost as fast as it can get, since NumPy's operations are optimized for arrays.  It is also much more legible than a loop, because it is both simple and short.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, but usually real performance improvements come when you evaluate the code at a function or even higher level.

During a good evaluation, you may find whole blocks that code be thrown away or rewritten to simplify the process.

Answer (score 0):

Profilers are useful AFTER you've cleaned up crufty not-very-legible code. irrespective of whether it's to be run once or N zillion times, you should not write code like that.

Why are you doing `float(q[i])` and `float(w[i])`? What type(s) is/are the elements of `q` and `w'?

If x and y are floats, then `x - y` will be a float too, so that's 3 apparently redundant occurrences of float() already.

Calling math.pow() instead of using the ** operator bears the overhead of lookups on 'math' and 'pow'.

Etc etc

See if the following code gives the same answers and reads better and is faster:

```
costsq = 0.0
for i in xrange(12):
    costsq += (q[i] - w[i]) ** 2
cost = math.sqrt(costsq)
```

After you've tested that and understood why the changes were made, you can apply the lessons to other Python code. Then if you have a lot more array or matrix work to do, consider using `numpy`.

Comment: the elements of list are i string format so have to use float i guess

Comment: @kaushik: consider converting the strings to floats on input using (for example) `q = map(float, q)` -- especially if they are used in more than one calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming q and w contain numbers the conversions to float are not necessary, otherwise you should convert the lists to a usable representation earlier (and separately from your calculation)

Given that your function seems to only be doing the equivalent of this:

```
cost = sum( (qi-wi)**2 for qi,wi in zip(q[:12],w) ) ** 0.5
```

Perhaps this form would execute faster.